# can't run jar file on Amazon AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, executable-jar

I'm trying to run a jar file of my Spring boot project on a Amazon AWS ec2 instance, but when I try this I get a message i do not understand (i have limited knowledge of linux...). Click the link below to see the screenhot with the message:

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH3Ss.jpg)

As you can see i've installed Java and copied the jar file to /home/ec2-user.
Can anyone explain me how to proceed? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: its hard to tell without knowing the purpose of your jar.. from the output it looks like its running jandex command. how did you package the app ?

Comment: Hi Frédéric, thanks for your quick reply. I packaged the app with IntelliJ (Menu --> Build --> Build Artifacts). Can this be an issue?

Comment: could be, can you check if you have a manifest file in your jar and edit the question with the manifest file

Comment: I had a manifest file in the jar file, but I managed to ​create a executable jar with Maven cli instead of Intellij, which also runs on the ec2 instance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you please confirm answer or add your ones that fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

you need rapackage the jar, if you use maven you do like this :

1-add this in your pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>your.main.calss.path</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2- run this commande for packaiging:

```
mvn package
```

3- run your jar

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```